# Will there be any conflict if I have MySQL (Xampp) and install PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have been using MySQL via Xampp in my Windows for a long time. I want to try and study PostgreSQL and by doing that, need to install from the PostgreSQL website. Will I encounter any conflicting ports or default paths? I'm not sure what to do or just uninstall PostgreSQL after using it to avoid conflicts in my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be absolutely fine. Even though MySQL and PostgreSQL are both databases, they run on different ports, store data in different directories and in general will both run at the same time without any problems.

Comment: Good to know, will now try to install and will update this questions if anything comes up which I doubt.